# Trying to replace data in a single key with php

Tags: php, json

I have a json file with about 35 entries.  I need to be able to update values in a particular key, based on form input. So if I wanted to just edit info in "id":"2".

Example from my file.json

```
    [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Bob Smith",
        "callsign": "500",
        "rank": "Sheriff",
        "region": "NA",
        "status": "Active",
        "dept": "BCSO"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Steve Rogers",
        "callsign": "537",
        "rank": "Under Sheriff",
        "region": "NA",
        "status": "Active",
        "dept": "BCSO"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Jane Smith",
        "callsign": "505",
        "rank": "Captain",
        "region": "NA",
        "status": "Active",
        "dept": "BCSO"
    }
    ]
```

Here's the code I was using:

```
$rlog = array();
$RosterFile = "./includes/roster.json";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($RosterFile);
$rlog = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$num = count($rlog);
$formdata = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'name'=>$name,
    'callsign'=>$sign,
    'rank'=>$rank,
    'region'=>$region,
    'status'=>$status,
    'dept'=>$dept
    );
array_push($rlog, $formdata);
$jsondata = json_encode($rlog, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
if (file_put_contents($RosterFile, $jsondata))
    { echo '<h3>Roster changes Updated</h3>'; }
    else { echo "error"; }
```

That could would actually add a new entry at the end of the json rather then  updating "2".  (I'd end up with 2 entries for id 2).

Comment: What have you tried, it's quite simple to loop over the array and change the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you index the decoded JSON by the `id` with `array_column` and build your replacement with the `id` then you can easily do a replacement.  Then re-index to get prettier JSON:

```
$rlog = array_column(json_decode($jsondata, true), null, 'id');

$formdata[$id] = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'name'=>$name,
    'callsign'=>$sign,
    'rank'=>$rank,
    'region'=>$region,
    'status'=>$status,
    'dept'=>$dept
    );

$rlog = array_values(array_replace($rlog, $formdata));
```

Or just replace the correct one by `id`:

```
$rlog = array_column(json_decode($jsondata, true), null, 'id');

$formdata = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'name'=>$name,
    'callsign'=>$sign,
    'rank'=>$rank,
    'region'=>$region,
    'status'=>$status,
    'dept'=>$dept
    );

$rlog[$id] = $formdata;
```

But actually, you should be able to just modify the original:

```
$rlog = array_column(json_decode($jsondata, true), null, 'id');

$rlog[$id] = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'name'=>$name,
    'callsign'=>$sign,
    'rank'=>$rank,
    'region'=>$region,
    'status'=>$status,
    'dept'=>$dept
    );

$rlog = array_values($rlog);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to update the second entry always you could do this:

```
$rlog[1] = $formdata;
```

instead of your `array_push` line.

I will also tell you that you are reading the content from the data, then changing it, then updating the file with the new content.  If another process changes the file between your read and your write, that new data will be lost.

If you wanted to make a function of it:

```
function update_array_element(array $input, int $index, $newData) {
    $input[$index] = $newData;
}
```

Note: The type-hinting is only available in php version >=7

Or to make it even more flexible:

```
function update_array_element(array $elements, int $id, $newData) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($elements); $i++) {
        if ($elements[$i]['id'] == $id) $elements[$i] = $newData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$id = 1;

$formdata = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'name'=>'somename',
    'callsign'=>'somesign',
    'rank'=>'somerank',
    'region'=>'somereligon',
    'status'=>'somestatus',
   // 'dept'=>$dept - omitted intentionally
);


$rlog = json_decode($jsondata, true);

//note the & pass by refrence
foreach($rlog as $key=>&$value) if($value['id'] == $formdata['id']) $value = array_replace($value, $formdata);

print_r($rlog);
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6d9e3dd5fe420146312d8a59f97098592562cc3)

Output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => somename
        [callsign] => somesign
        [rank] => somerank
        [region] => somereligon
        [status] => somestatus
        [dept] => BCSO
    )
    ....
```

Done,

Comment: This isn't what OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok I fix it. It was still simple.  I even accounted for missing keys in `$formdata`  and it's still 1 line of code...